# MVC 4 application render time with Visual Studio 2012

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012

When I run my mvc application using Visual Studio 2012 on Chrome, my page takes 36s to render - saw this using mini-profiler. When I host the project on a remote server and hit the server for the page, then it takes 36s on the first hit. But on subsequent hits, it dramatically reduces to 1s or less. Any thoughts on why this might be? On the remote server, when we restart the application pool, we are seeing it take 36s.

So question is, is it taking that long because of IIS allocating resources to the site or is there something else wrong with our setup? Our development time is really taking a hit with the amount of time that it takes each time we have to debug our project. Build and then takes 36s each time to render the page we are debugging.

Answer (score 1):

When you say "run", I'm assuming you meaning debug. Debug rebuilds the project and then once it loads the browser, all the standard initialization for a first time load must be done each time. The fact that it takes the same amount of time (36s) as the application pool spin-up on your server seems to bear this out.

FWIW, you only *need* to debug your project once per Visual Studio session to have IIS Express fire up. Afterwards, you can simply rebuild your project and refresh the browser directly after (without using debug in Visual Studio) to test your changes. And, you only need to rebuild if you made changes to any *.cs files. Razor views, web.config, etc. will reflect their changes on next page load without a rebuild. The only thing you lose doing it this way is the debug ability, obviously enough. You'll just get a standard yellow page of death instead of automatically jumping to the offending bit of code in Visual Studio. But, I've found that unless I actually need to debug, this method is much quicker to develop with.

Answer (score 0):

A few possibilities come to mind:

**View Compilation**

By default when you work on your project in Visual Studio, the views are compiled on-demand.  While 36 sec seems like a *very* long time to compile the view for the first page, this could be a contributing factor.  If your page changes, it has to be re-compiled.  To eliminate this as a factor when performing measurements, you can edit your .csproj file with a text editor and change the line

```
<MvcBuildViews>false</MvcBuildViews>
```

to

```
<MvcBuildViews>true</MvcBuildViews>
```

(this can also be a useful setting in general).

**Other Initialization Overhead**

If you are doing much initialization when your app starts (perhaps pre-loading some data from a file or database), that initialization must happen every time the web server starts or the app domain recycles.  In Visual Studio, I find that the web server can restart at surprising (to me) times.  Add some logging to see if you're running startup code during a particular benchmark run, and see how much overhead that is.

**Entity Framework**

For some reason, Entity Framework runs *much* slower when debugging.  If you're doing a lot of data access through EF, that could account for some of the difference.

Comment: First thing I did was change the MVCBuildViews="true" but that didn't change anything. In regard to pre-loading data, is that bundling? Is that automapper configurations?

Comment: Bundling should not take more than a few to maybe a few 100 milliseconds.  In DEBUG mode (based on the web.config setting, not the build setting in VS), bundling isn't actually done but rather the files in the bundle are passed through unaltered.  So if anything DEV would be faster.  With pre-loading data, I meant perhaps you load up data from your database or something similar in `Application_Start()`.  In any event I would measure how much time is spent in `Application_Start()`.

Comment: When we directly put the scripts on the page instead of using the bundling feature in debug mode, our startup seems to be much faster. This link(http://todd-carter.com/post/2012/06/10/mini-me-fication-in-system-web-optimization-rc-is-evil/) seems to say the same thing but it seems like Microsoft has updated this but I'm not so sure. We are not using the rc version.

Comment: Just ran a stopwatch that begins at the beginning of Application_Start and ends at the end of Application_Start and I found out that it takes 338ms. Which is MUCH smaller than the 36s it is taking.